# How to encrypt a file using Bash?

Tags: bash, encryption

I am trying to encrypt a test file I have and decrypt the file using a bash script.

I searched online and found I can use openssl and `salt` to do this.

I found the following code online:

```
FNAME=$1

if [[ -z "$FNAME" ]]; then
    echo "cryptde <name of file>"
    echo "  - cryptde is a script to decrypt des3 encrypted files"
    exit;
fi

openssl des3 -d -salt -in "$FNAME" -out "${FNAME%.[^.]*}"
```

How does it work?

Comment: What part do you not understand? Read the man page for each command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. FNAME=$1

This assigns the first parameter to FNAME

2. if [[ -z "$FNAME" ]]; then

If the string $FNAME is zero in length, then echo the help output and exit

3. openssl des3 -d -salt -in "$FNAME" -out "${FNAME%.[^.]*}"

This line runs the openssl command's des3 module (man des3) takes $FNAME as input file name, then writes output to $FNAME without a .extension. This final argument is a regular expression that strips the extension off (.[NOT .]any number of times.